# How to remove 'worklight settings' from menu options

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I implemented WL.OptionsMenu with 4 options. But, default menu option "Worklight settings" is not getting removed from those options. How to remove that menu option from visibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Worklight project, open application-descriptor.xml and change the following in the Android environment element.

**From:**

```
worklightSettings include="true"/>
```

**To**

```
worklightSettings include="false"/>
```

Comment: How to do this change in Android project because this project is on different maching

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Explain yourself.